# I want OpenID on GAE/J. I don't want yet another +100kB JAR. Am I lost?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, openid

Usually people ask for 'best library', but I assume OpenID authentication is only a couple of requests in/out...? And I'm on GAE where more JARs means slower cold-start. For example *openid4java-0.9.5.jar* has 190kB. That seems like an insanely high cost for some URL reading and text parsing.

Am I missing something? Is it more complicated then what is needed when requesting access_token and user info from Facebook?

Is there some well explained howto? ([This looks good](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html) but seems to be useful only for Google Accounts.)
Or is the authentication that complicated (or identity providers that non-compatible) that I should just accept +190kB and add them to my JARs? (Or maybe wait with OpenID for now.)

Comment: App Engine now supports OpenID natively. Is there a reason you can't use that?

Comment: The only reason would be that I did not know that. Silly, I know. :P Thank you, Nick!! Could you give me some URL please? I'm unable to google anything that would look 'official' enough.

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/overview.html

Comment: I already have it, the link has shown when I switched from Google Account authentication to Federated login. :) If you care about rep. write this as answer, I will give you the credit. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Use the Federated login characteristics provided by the Google App Engine.
Federated Login refers to any service that allows users to create a single ID or account and use it to authenticate with various services. **OpenID is the only Federated Login supported by the Google App Engine Users service**.

You can find more information about the Authentication Options here:
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/overview.html#Authentication_Options

And I would recommend to read the "User Experience summary for Federated Login" also:
http://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/UXFedLogin/summary

Comment: Thanks, I already got the answer, see above. (It has not been marked because it was given in a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's always better to use a good library than to write thing by oneself. Is 100 kB a big amount for a server-side code? If you really want to reduce the size of your final code, better use a good obfuscator, for example ProGuard can shorten method names and remove unnecessary code.

But remember that premature optimization is the root of all evil - such stripping JARs may have big sense for applets or other code that users have to download, but IMO has little sense for server-side applications.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it is reasonable to use library for something that can be done in 5 lines of code. But it is very common thing to see...

Answer (score 0):

+1 for the default Open Id (though experimental) support in GAE

Nevertheless, I've used RPX (now janrain) : http://www.janrain.com/products/engage eariler. Nicely fits into your requirement - no jars, least amount of code and support for all login openid / social interfaces. All you need a publicly accessible call back URL.

Check it out!